# Why Would Journey Builder Update Some Service Cloud Contacts But Not Others?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, standard-objects, updaterecord

I have a serious problem with a journey which is supposed to create and/or update Sales cloud objects.

The journey is supposed to do the following:

- Create Individual Record in Individual Object for Existing Contacts (and some leads)
- Updates Contact or Lead Record in Salesforce with the Individual ID from the Individual Record Created in previous step
- Create Contact Point Type Consent Record for the individual using the same individual ID

I am running this journey in JB but seeing strange results from the Update Contact Object activity. It is updating the individual ID on some contact records but not others and there is no apparent pattern.

In all cases the individual record and contact point type consent record are being created successfully.
In around 50% of cases the individual ID is being correctly updated to the contact or lead object, but in the rest it is being ignored.

- ContactKey exists for all records and is from Salesforce Contact Object via the connector
- Entry data is the same for all records with all mandatory fields included
- Permission set in Sales Cloud is correct
- Journey history is showing everything as being completed successfully

Has anyone come across this issue. It makes no difference whether the entry group is small (8 records) or 1000 records.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Update - I think I might have solved this - there is a hidden mandatory field on contact that does not show as mandatory on the JB activity.